# Problem of progress bar animation when scroll to top

Tags: angular, electron

I'm working on an electron app with angular.
I found my progress bar animation problem when I was changing pages with scrollTo function.

Here is my situation.

My router-outlet is in a div, but in some pages the contents are too long, 
so there is a progress bar on the side of div.
I add a class to the div and use 'scrollTop' to let scroll bar back to top.
And my progress bar animation start with 100% and bounce back to 0 immediately, even if I fill the progress value with 0.

I also use the method Angular provide 'scrollPositionRestoration' in RoterModule, but it didn't work with router-outlet in a div.

Are there any solutions to prevent animation problem and scroll the div back to top.
Thanks!

app.component.html ->

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class='logoContainer'>
        <img [src]='logo' class='logo'/>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts ->

```
  onActivate(event) {
      // scroll to top
      document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].scrollTo(0, 0);
   }
```

[Here is the gif to show what happend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NndfG.gif)

Comment: Hey! Would you mind creating a small version of this app in CodePen or sandbox.io (or similar)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with code sandbox, I kept getting error there.
So I upload source code of simple demo version to my github repo. 
I only use angular without electron in this project.
Here's link.
https://github.com/pc0805a/progressBarTest

Comment: I created a codesandbox for it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pc0805a/progressBarTest - going to try play around with it soon